# GMAP Module map not showing markers after updates with js error: Clusterer is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I've recently taken a live site down for updates and development. I have updated from core 7.39 to 7.41 and updated numerous modules including jQuery update. After the updated, I noticed that my map was zooming to it's max extent and not displaying markers. The only diagnostic error I get is an `Uncaught ReferenceError: Clusterer is not defined.`I can confirm the the markers are being loaded by going into console and logging the drupal.settings.gmap.aut1map.markers variable. I don't have a lot of experience with the GMAP module, so any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: tried to update to dev version, no real change. 
UPDATE: From what I can tell, it appears that the GMAP version I have installed is has this patch applied [GMAP Clusterer.js issues](https://www.drupal.org/node/2175929)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it's actually a rookie mistake. Updating the module wipes out all the third party js files you download. took me longer than it should to figure this out.

Comment: WHICH issue is it?

Comment: Hi pierre, just updated. As above, I'm not sure exactly.

Comment: so, it's my own fault, the script wasn't in the right place.

Comment: Hm, think I also made such mistake in the past when I didn't realise the real purpose of the typical libraries subfolder to put module related libraries (and instead incorrectly put such libraries in the module subfolder). If you then update a module you run into a similar problem, ie the library is gone (or moved to some backup folder at best)